# como consigo guardar un string en una variable al presionar el boton (boton22)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

raiz=Tk()

raiz.title("Acceso SLOL")\
raiz.geometry("850x500")

boton22=Button(raiz,text="presione 1",)\
boton22.place(anchor="center",relx=.1,rely=.1)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para guardar una variable es con un Entry, se declara de la siguiente forma.
Solo dejo como nota que se tiene que declarar la variable donde se va a guardar como StringVar().

```
variable_string = StringVar()#Variable declarada
entry= Entry(raiz,textvariable = variable_string)#Entry para obtener la variable
```

Para obtener la variable es con el siguiente comando.

```
variable_string.get()
```

Si tienes alguna duda con mucho gusto te ayudo.